# Git Extensions shows results that don't match search filters as well as results that match

Tags: git, search, versioning, git-extensions

Git extensions when searching using different filters (for example, commit message) will show results with commit messages that don't contain my search string.  This is really annoying is there any way to prevent this?

Command line git filtering using --grep shows only the appropriate commits.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is that when filtering you must select branch but it is defaultly blank.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't fix the problem. I have 2.47.3 of git extensions.

Comment: Actually this sort of worked.  It eliminated all non matching results except for one merge commit in my case and it also eliminated a few results that matched without the branch filter.  Any way to improve the results even further?